# Correct way to handle multiple requests in UniMRCP Plugin

Tags: unimrcp

I'm trying to create a `UniMRCP` plugin. It is not clear from the documentation how multiple simultaneous requests from clients are supposed to be handled with the Plugin. Which of the options below is the case?

- The server creates a plugin on a different thread for each request.
- The server queues the requests and sends them serially.
- The plugin is supposed to manage the different requests based on session ID.
- other option.

Based on the answer to the above, what would be the best strategy to implement the plugin.